# LEFT OUTER JOIN giving slow query

Tags: mysql

I have this query which is causing issues, it's running at 0.10 seconds on average.

z_watching has 10k rows, title has 40k rows, z_tv_episodes has 400k rows

Most columns have indexes.

I've tried switching to a simple WHERE query but that doesn't help. The issue seems to be when the sorting of the episodes happen. The OR doesn't seem to be the issue.

The query does this: find all shows a user is watching in z_watching, finds all the corresponding shows in title, and then sorts all the episodes in z_tv_episodes (finding episodes that the user hasn't watched and that have already aired).

```
SELECT * FROM z_watching z
LEFT OUTER JOIN title t ON z.media_id = t.media_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN z_tv_episodes e ON 
   (e.media_id = t.media_id 
    AND e.episode_number > z.episode_watched 
    AND e.season_number = z.season_watched 
    AND e.episode_airdate < "2016-05-12" 
    AND e.episode_airdate != "0000-00-00")
 OR 
   (e.media_id = t.media_id 
    AND e.season_number > z.season_watched 
    AND e.episode_airdate < "2016-05-12" 
    AND e.episode_airdate != "0000-00-00"
    )
WHERE 
z.user_id = 1
ORDER BY 
t.title, e.episode_airdate ASC
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Given the size of your tables, `0.1` seconds doesn't sound particularly bad to me.  What is the context where the running time is such an issue?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not really an issue for now. z_tv_episodes is likely to get bigger in the future and it's difficult to cache that query for very long as users interact a lot with it. I thought anything above 0.01 needed to be looked at.

Comment: I would need the result of the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to help determine what improvements can be made.

Comment: 0.1sec is pretty fine for your tables ...

Comment: @Arjan screenshot: http://puu.sh/oP7d4/b72bc39886.png